# Format data in Repeater

Tags: asp.net, controls

The result of a stored procedure will look like this.

```
    1   Group Admin     user1    
    1   Group Admin     user2 
    1   Group Admin     user3
    1   Group Admin     user4 
    1   Group Admin     user5    
    2   Group Second    user6    
    2   Group Second    user7 
    2   Group Second    user8    
    2   Group Second    user9    
    2   Group Second    user10 
    2   Group Second    user11
```

I want to format the data as shown in picture .

The question is related with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8351660/group-items-in-checkboxlist-gridview-in-asp-net-3-5)

I think `Repeater` is the best control to use here. What you think ? If so, how can I format it ?
 Is `GridView` with row merging a good idea ?

[image]

After reading the answer

```
// Page_Load
DataSet ds = GetAllUsers();

ViewState["UserRoles"] = ds;

rptParent.DataSource = ds;
rptParent.DataBind();
```

Other events

```
// ItemDataBound
 protected void rptParent_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            RepeaterItem item = e.Item;
            if ((item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) ||
                (item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
            {
                string s = e.Item.DataItem.ToString();
                string roleID = ((HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hidRoleId")).Value;
                Repeater childRepeater = (Repeater)item.FindControl("rptChild");
                string filterExp = "RoleId=" + roleID;
                DataTable dtChild = ((DataSet)ViewState["UserRoles"]).Tables[0];
                DataRow[] dr = dtChild.Select(filterExp);
                childRepeater.DataSource = dr;
                childRepeater.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

Mark up

```
// MarkUp
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptParent" OnItemDataBound="rptParent_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hidRoleId" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("RoleId")%>' />
                            <asp:Label ID="lblRoleName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("RoleName")%>'></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox4" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox5" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox6" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <asp:Repeater ID="rptChild" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hidRoleId" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("UserId")%>' />
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UserName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox7" runat="server" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox8" runat="server" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox9" runat="server" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

I get the following output

[image]

But the Group name is also repeating :(. This is NOT what I want

Answer (score 1):

I would use a nested repeater.

With Linq you can easily group your data and bind this to the outer repeater (and set the values for the 3 top checkboxes) and then the OnDataBound of the outer repeater can set the User list as datasource for the nested repeater.

Markup would look like:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="ParentRepeater" OnItemDataBound="ParentRepeater_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
            // Markup for the three top checkboxes
            <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="ChildRepeater">
                <ItemTemplate>
                   // Inner layout for each user with checkboxes
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And in the code behind:

```
protected void ParentRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    RepeaterItem item = e.Item;
    if ((item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) ||
        (item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
    {
        var data = item.DataItem as <YourType>;

        Repeater childRepeater = (Repeater)item.FindControl("ChildRepeater");
        childRepeater .DataSource = data.<InnerResults>;
        childRepeater .DataBind();
    }
}
```

If you need to use an anonymous type for your grouping have a look at the Tuple<,> class. That can help if you want to cast the item.DataItem back to a known type.

Comment: `var data = item.DataItem as DataTable;
                Repeater childRepeater = (Repeater)item.FindControl("ChildRepeater");
                string filterExp = "RoleId=" + roleID;
                DataRow[] dtChild = data.Select(filterExp);
                childRepeater.DataSource = dtChild;
                childRepeater.DataBind();` It does not work. I get 'data' as null.

Comment: What is the type of DateItem? If it's not a DataTable the 'as' operator will return null

Comment: It is of Object type. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeateritem.dataitem.aspx. So here it will be `DataRowView`. If so, how can I query it using LINQ ?

Comment: I know the type is object, I meant what do you put into it. You cast it to a DataTable so you somewhere put a DataTable in the DataSource of the Repeater?